# combining blits and gdi drawings (do not work, blinks)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

I am tryin to combine texture blit with gdi drawing on top of it
 (by

```
    void draw()
    {
     StretchDIBits(hdc, 0, 0, CLIENT_X, CLIENT_Y, 0, 0, BUF_X, BUF_Y, buffer, &bmi,    DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
     TextOut(hdc, 10, 10, "Hello World", 11);
    }
```

hdc is obrained once at setup time by GetDC but it is probably ok; this above i run both in idle loop 100 times per second and also fron OnPain message; and this is not working good just becouse TextOut result just blinks, the rest is all ok - could someone tell me some advice how to remove this blinking and obtain stable TextOut result ? much tnx

Comment: Problem isn't quite clear. Are you saying that this keeps re-drawing constantly? If so, that usually means you forgot to call EndPaint, which is what validates the window (i.e., says it doesn't need drawing any more).

Comment: When I draw texture with StretchDIBits i just nod need nothing more and it works. Do I need some f-ckin BeginPaint EndPaint with TextOut stuff? Tried it a while ago seem not to work ok. I want to draw() not only in WM_PAINT but at eny time, Does TextOut changing HDC context data immediately ?

Comment: On Windows, you normally *only* want to draw in response to WM_PAINT. For any other drawing, you just save the data you need to do the drawing, then InvalidateRect so you'll get a WM_PAINT, at which point you'll draw (I know that sounds roundabout, and it is, but it's how you normally do things on Windows anyway).

Comment: OK, but 1) I wrote a game-like progs with idle loop and drawing 100 Hz - there I have blitter and I do blits into window and it work even without OnPaint() at all (it is simpler just drawing in loop not to consider some message journeys)   2) it does not probably resolves a problem with blinking - do you mean that TextOut cannot be used and will not work outside WMPaint handler? (I will try to check it with GetDC and releaseDc or something)

Comment: I'm not saying TextOut can't work outside a WM_PAINT handler -- I am saying that's the traditional way to use it. Without looking at more code than what's above, it's hard to guess what else may be cause the problems you're seeing. Updating at 100 Hz is pointless unless you're sure the monitor in use updates that fast (happened with CRTs, rare with LCDs).

Comment: with InvalidateRect result is just tjhe same, global hdc or GetDc/ReleaseDc also do not matter - seem that it is a physical blinking problem - probably to much time between blit and textout results - got no idea how to resolve it

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_buffer#Double_buffering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need "double buffer" to avoid blinking.

Create memory DC `CreateCompatibleDC` select in it bitmap with proper size created with `CreateCompatibleBitmap` and paint in this memory DC.

When your picture is ready - `BitBlt` it on your window DC.

Comment: Semms so - But here I got some dc with my blitted texture so I think I should just TextOut into it before blitting it Seem that i shoul dmaybe create compatible blit into it text out into it and blit into dc ? Much code probably... Is there some example :(

Comment: This may vary. If your texture updated every time - will be OK to TextOut on this (existing) mem dc. But usually textures are created/initialized on startup (or rarely). So you need to create another buffer (mem dc) to avoid texture damanges.

Answer (score 1):

This is natural. You draw a DIB on the DC. And the immediately you draw a text which is (presumably) placed so that its bounding rectangle overlaps with the one used in `StretchDIBits`.

In simple words: you draw something, then you draw something else on the same place. This will blink. What else did you expect?

In order to avoid blinking you should use so-called double-buffering. This means:

1. Create a bitmap of the adequate size.
2. Create a DC (so-called memory DC)
3. Select this bitmap into it.
4. Draw your DIB on this DC (not the one that you initially obtained).
5. Draw your text.
6. Finally use `BitBlt` to transfer the image from bitmap to your initial DC.
7. Don't forget to cleanup things: `DeleteObject` for the DIB, `DeleteDC` for memory DC.

Optionally you may keep your bitmap instead of creating it each time you need to draw something. It's better from the performance point of view: Doing `StretchXXXX` is heavy, plus drawing on the screen from bitmap is much faster that drawing a DIB (assuming the video card supports 2D acceleration).

Comment: DAMN< it wil complicate my code, Now I just used the TWO LINES (!) to draw it all :-(.... :/ probably i will do it but L8R now I think I can Textout above the texture (not over it) or so (text out is just for debug like (profiler) info) :/